# regex to get String which is outside of brackets

Tags: java, regex

i am searching a way(regex expression) to get anything outside the brackets in java

like

```
String sample = "Hi all(igi)";
```

Output like

```
Hi all
```

Searched a lot but not able to find it on stack or google

What i am trying

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:[^<>(^)]++)").matcher(abc);
while (m.find()) {
    String newName = m.group(0);
    System.out.println(newName);

}
```

It is giving me both text

also i want a regex expression not a workaround (i guess it can be done in regex only)
also explain the regex expression  if you got the answer i want to learn how to achieve it

Comment: Are you looking for `s.split("\\([^()]*\\)")`?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use replaceAll with some regex `\(.*?\)` which mean replace every thing between brackets so in the end you will get only the result that is not between the brackets :

```
sample = sample.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "");
```

Example:

```
Input                        Output

Hi all(igi)                  Hi all
Hi all(igi) Some string      Hi all Some string
```